# formatDateTime in Power Automate Desktop

Tags: power-automate-desktop

I am trying to assign the current datetime to two variables in Power Automate Desktop - one as the date in yyyyMMdd format and one as the time in HHmm format.

The steps I have is to use 'Get current date and time' and store that value into the variable CurrentDateTime.

I have then created a variable called Date and I'm setting the variable value to be `%formatDateTime(CurrentDateTime,'yyyyMMdd')%` and set the time variable to `%formatDateTime(CurrentDateTime,'HHmm')%`

I keep receiving the error Function name 'formatDateTime' is invalid. What am I doing wrong? Microsoft lists formatDateTime as an expression here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/workflow-definition-language-functions-reference#formatDateTime

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are confusing Power Automate with Power Automate Desktop.
The link you provide is for Power Automate, so those functions won't work in the PADesktop.

There is an action named [Convert datetime to text](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-automate/desktop-flows/actions-reference/text#converttexttodatetime) in PAD, you can specify the formats you would like there

The action lets you pick from existing formats or you can specify one.
[image: action convert dt to text]

copy this code to PAD to see a custom example

```
Text.ConvertDateTimeToText.FromCustomDateTime DateTime: CurrentDateTime CustomFormat: $'''yyyy*MM*dd HH`mm''' Result=> FormattedDateTime
```

Comment: Thank you. Convert datetime to text is just what I needed

Answer (score -1):

It seems like you are encountering an issue with the syntax or usage of the `formatDateTime` function in Power Automate Desktop. Let's break down the steps for setting the Date and Time variables:

1. **Get current date and time:**

   - Use the 'Get current date and time' action and store the value into the variable `CurrentDateTime`.
2. **Format Date:**

   - Create a variable called `Date`.
   - Set the variable value using the following expression:

     ```
     %formatDateTime(CurrentDateTime, 'yyyyMMdd')%
     ```
3. **Format Time:**

   - Create a variable called `Time`.
   - Set the variable value using the following expression:

     ```
     %formatDateTime(CurrentDateTime, 'HHmm')%
     ```

Make sure that you have used the correct syntax for the `formatDateTime` function, and the variables `Date` and `Time` are correctly defined.

If you're still encountering issues, consider the following troubleshooting steps:

- Double-check the spelling and case of the function and variable names.
- Ensure that the `CurrentDateTime` variable is populated correctly after the 'Get current date and time' action.
- Verify that you are using the correct date and time format strings ('yyyyMMdd' and 'HHmm').

Another thing you could do is:

1. **Get current date and time:**

   - Use the 'Get current date and time' action and store the value into the variable `CurrentDateTime`.
2. **Format Date:**

   - Create a variable called `Date`.
   - Use the 'Format date/time' action and set the format to `yyyyMMdd`. Input the `CurrentDateTime` variable as the source, and store the formatted date in the `Date` variable.
3. **Format Time:**

   - Create a variable called `Time`.
   - Use the 'Format date/time' action and set the format to `HHmm`. Input the `CurrentDateTime` variable as the source, and store the formatted time in the `Time` variable.

Ensure that you are using the available actions in Power Automate Desktop for date and time formatting, as the functions and syntax might differ from traditional expressions.

Comment: This is what I have done, but PAD keeps giving the error "Function name 'formatDateTime' is invalid"